# Sub or function not defined vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a compiling error with vba but I do not understand where is the problem:
Here is my code:

```
Sub etat()
Dim i As Single
Set plage = Range("D2:A24")
Dim etat As String

For i = 2 To 23 'début de la boucle
    If (Sheet("Voitures").Cell(i, D).Value < 2002) Then
        Sheet("Voitures").Cell(i, H).Value = "TRY"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

The error is Sub or function is not define

Comment: `Sheets` and `Cells`, not `Sheet` and `Cell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is your modified code
use below

```
Sub etat()
Dim i As Single
Set plage = Range("D2:A24")
Dim etat As String

' d and h are columns
Dim d As Integer
Dim h As Integer
d = 4
h = 6

For i = 2 To 23 'début de la boucle
    If (Sheets("Voitures").Cells(i, d).Value < 2002) Then
        Sheets("Voitures").Cells(i, h).Value = "TRY"
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: thank you so much sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

`If (Sheet`.. should be `If (Sheets`.. plural

`Cell` should be `Cells` .. plural

variable D needs declaring and initialising with a value

variable H needs declaring and initialising with a value

Comment: D and H are suppose to be the columns, i have never used vba before so i'm not sure how to declare columns

Comment: You declare the variables with Dim, the variable name and the data type e.g. Dim H as Long then on a new line H=2 - as you have done with your variable i.